# Can't execute .exe with an additional param using the .bat file

Tags: windows, batch-file, netbeans, console, cmd

I need to run NetBeans 7.4 with an additional param such as --locale en:US.
I have no problems doing this using wingows 7 console like this:

```
>b:
>cd "Program Files\NetBeans 7.4\bin"
>netbeans64.exe --locale en:US
```

But this way is very cumbersome. Besides it closes the program itself if I close the console.
So I tryed to make a .bat file with the following content:

```
@echo off
echo Netbeans
start "netbeans" "b:\Program Files\NetBeans 7.4\bin\netbeans64.exe --locale en:US"
pause
exit
```

However this solution doesn't work. It tells that it can't find this file. If I remove the param '--locale en:US' it founds it. But it is necessary to use this param.
Something should be changed, but how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Almost done. Just change where the quotes are placed

```
start "netbeans" "b:\Program Files\NetBeans 7.4\bin\netbeans64.exe" --locale en:US
```

And, for the console problem, from netbeans launcher documentation

- Default behaviour - parent process console is attached. This means if
  netbeans.exe is started from console it is "reused" for output, if
  netbeans.exe is started by shortcut no console is created
- If option "--console new" is specified netbeans.exe creates new
  console for output. This is useful if you want to start NB by
  shortcut and you want still see console output or if you need to
  start several NB instances with different user dirs. Console window
  will have correct icon and corresponding title e.g. netbeans
  --userdir d:\test_userdir --console new) so it is easy to distinguish which console belongs to certain NB instance
- If option "--console suppress" is specified no output will be written
  to console you invoke it from

In this moment i have no access to netbeans installation to test, but it seems there are three ways

Start with `--console new` so netbeans gets its own console and do not depend on cmd

Start with `--console suppress` to dettach from console

Create a shortcut to netbeans (with your parameters, of course). If it is necessary to start netbeans from console, start the .lnk file (shortcut) instead of netbeans executable.

As said, i can not try. Maybe this works.

Comment: Great answer! But it still terminates a program if I close the console. Any suggestions how to avoid this inconvenience?

Comment: Yes. I confess I had seen this message ("use --console supress") already, but understood it just now. Thank you very much! (a little notice - "suppress", not "supress"). All other suggested ways work also.